# show element on specific user with nodejs

Tags: node.js

I'm building a social app and under each image I have a comment section. I want to render every comment and to include a delete button only to the user that made the comment. Can anyone help me handle this?
here is how I render the comments:

```
    {{# each image.comments}}
<div class="comments clearfix">
<img src="{{this.avatar}}" class="logo">
<span><strong>{{this.userName}}</strong><br> {{this.comment}}</span>
</div>
{{/each}}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You can track the comments for the images in the database. When a user comments for an image store that comment as well as check if the user Id is same as the owner id of the image. If so, then the user who just comments must be the owner and set a property like "isOwner = true" for the comment, along with the comment text.

And in the front end you can check this property and set a delete icon..

```
{{#each image.comments}}
<div class="comments clearfix">
<img src="{{this.avatar}}" class="logo">
<span><strong>{{this.userName}}</strong><br> {{this.comment}}</span>
{{#if this.isOwner}}
<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
{{/if}}
</div>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: my question was about the case where the user who comments is not the owner of the image.i think i need a way to check every comment

Comment: i see.  In that case you have to check with the user in current session.